# Mass calculation of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, geometry, discrete-mathematics

I have to calculate the mass of a cylinder for a particular application but it's not important at this step; I have the following parameters:

- $r=1\space mm = 10^{-3}\space m$
- $d= 9*10^{3} \space \frac{Kg}{m^{3}}$
- $l=10\space cm = 10^{-2} \space m$

We know that

- $m=d*V=d*(\pi*r^{2}*l)$

and we know of course that

- $V=\pi*r^{2}*l=3.14*10^{-3}*10^{-3}*10^{-2}=3.14*(10^{-8})$

Now, the expected value is $m=2.83*10^{-3} \space Kg$ but I can't obtain this result, maybe because I change in a wrong way the scale of $d$.
Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: The result is off by a factor of $10$. Are you sure the data are correct?

Comment: By the way, I don't see how you "change in a wrong way the scale of ".

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yes I'm sure...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca a $Kg$ is 1000 times bigger thank a $g$ so I think that I have $9*10^{3}*10^{-4}$

Comment: I found your error: $10\ \text{cm}=10\times10^{-2}\ \text{m}=10^{-1}\ \text{m}$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca PERFECT!!! Thank you so much. Now everything it's ok. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: @Intelligentipauca if you text your message like answer at my question, I quote you like best answer. Thx